# Unable to show all the words on Highcharts wordcloud

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I think this question might have been asked earlier but there were no correct solutions to this. So I am facing a issue with wordcloud High Charts where I am unable to display all the words that are being supplied to data array. It might be that the words are to long. So The array consists of 20 words but the wordcloud always displays 18 or less I tried changing the maxFontSize and fontFamily but no luck.Here is the codepen 
https://codepen.io/karankia/pen/XqMXPd and here is a code snippet

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
series: [{
type: 'wordcloud',
data: data,
name: 'Occurrences'
}],
title: {
text: 'Wordcloud of Lorem Ipsum'
}
});
```

As you can see on the codepen it's only displaying 17-18 words at a time.

Comment: This problem is reported as a bug on github: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/7241 You can find a workaround in the comments.

Comment: Thanks got it working, the workaround seems to disable the rotation. I have updated my code pen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by the workaround on github you need to disable the rotation. The following code snippet is an updated fix.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
series: [{
type: 'wordcloud',
data: data,
name: 'Occurrences',
rotation: {
    from: 0,
  to: 0
},
spiral: 'rectangular',
placementStrategy: 'center'
}],
 title: {
 text: 'Wordcloud of Lorem Ipsum'
 }
 });
```

Here is the updated link to codepen: https://codepen.io/karankia/pen/XqMXPd